# Select and count from two tables

Tags: mysql

How can select and count from two tables using mysqli query loop.

Here is the table structure

```
table1 = categories 
id | catname
-------------
1  | cat1
2  | cat2
3  | cat3
```

so on.

```
table2 =  articles
id | article | catid
---------------------
1  | art1    | 2
2  | art2    | 2
3  | art3    | 1
4  | art4    | 3
```

I need this to be displayed like

```
cat 1 - 1 articles
cat 2 - 2 articles
cat 3 - 1 articles
```

Can anyone point me out how to do this using mysqli query?

Comment: JFYI: your database is called mysql, not mysqli

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want this in a single column then you can use the following:

```
select 
  concat(c.catname, ' - ', a.Total, ' articles') list
from categories c
inner join
(
  select count(*) Total,
    catid
  from articles
  group by catid
) a
  on c.id = a.catid
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81660/3)

Or you can do this without the subquery:

```
select 
  concat(c.catname, ' - ', count(*), ' articles') list
from categories c
inner join articles a
  on c.id = a.catid
group by c.catname;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81660/6).  The result is:

```
|              LIST |
---------------------
| cat1 - 1 articles |
| cat2 - 2 articles |
| cat3 - 1 articles |
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT 
    c.catname,
    COUNT(*)
FROM categories c
INNER JOIN articles a
    ON c.id = a.catid
GROUP BY 
    c.catname
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT CONCAT(C.catname, ' - ', A.articles, ' Articles')
FROM   categories C
       INNER JOIN articles A
         ON C.id = A.catid
GROUP  BY A.catid
ORDER  BY C.catname
```

Comment: Your answer has been automatically flagged as being of low quality. This is probably because you have no explanation of _why_ your solution is correct.